# AWS start instance from cmd line specifying args to launch script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I need to be able to startup AWS EC2 instances quickly from one of my AMI images and at launch run a script to bootstrap the instance. I know I can do this with user data but I need to be able to pass the script an argument that will be different each time the instance is started.

If I use Start-EC2Instance from [AWS Tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html) I cant see a way to either pass the user data or pass agrs to the launch script.

Any  help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong command. Take a look at [**New-EC2Instance**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-EC2Instance.html)

```
Synopsis

Invokes the RunInstances method against Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud.
Syntax

New-EC2Instance
-ImageId <String>
....
-UserData <String>
-UserDataFile <String>
....
Description

Launches a specified number of instances of an AMI for which you have permissions.
```